# Can't add a # sign to the name of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

The top line in my array is:

```
string [] F# = new string[7];
```

I have a different string called

```
string [] F
```

and it tells me that "F is already defined in this scope." I am just trying to figure out how to fix this because I need it to be F# and not anything else.

Comment: Since the answer has already been given, I'll offer Fsharp as an alternative variable name. This is no different then trying to name a variable f++. There are certain things you just can't do.

Comment: # is reserved for pre-processor directives. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, plain and simple.

The '#' character is reserved for preprocessor directives in C#.

I also question the urgent need to name an array reference 'F#'.

Comment: @UnknownM1 Check [the C# spec, section 2.4.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx, any C# identifier must start with a character from the class Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, or Lo and the rest of the characters must be from Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc, or Cf.

`#` is Po, and so not in the list.

It's possible to give something that name in .NET if you really need to through reflection or expressions (the .NET rules are looser than the C# rules) but that's generally not very useful for precisely the reason that you can't access it through C# one you've done so.